# Mongoengine custom validation with modify

Tags: python, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I am trying to apply custom validation on a Mongoengine [modify](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document.modify) operation as seen below:

```
class Form(Document):

    fields = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Field))

    def modify(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for field in self.fields:
            if not [field for field in self.fields if field.type == "email"]:
                raise ValidationError("Form must have an email field")

        super(Form, self).modify(**kwargs)

     def update_form(self, modify_kwargs):
         return self.modify(**modify_kwargs)
```

However when I call `update_form`, the custom validation does not take the updated data into account in `modify`. Is there some sort of a pre-hook for doing this type of validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're verifying against the objects field attribute rather than kwargs. But make sure each field is an object that contains .type. You shouldn't be using the python reserved word type though.

```
class Form(Document):

fields = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Field))

def modify(self, *args, **kwargs):
     if not [field for field in kwargs.get('fields', []) if field.type == "email"]:
         raise ValidationError("Form must have an email field")

    super(Form, self).modify(**kwargs)

 def update_form(self, modify_kwargs):
     return self.modify(**modify_kwargs)
```